# primitive roots, field dimension

Tags: roots

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $m$-th root of $1$.

Determine the values of $m$ such that: $[\mathbb Q$($\zeta$):$\mathbb Q$]$=2$.

The only thing I have in mind is that $[\mathbb Q $($\zeta$):$\mathbb Q$]=$\varphi (n)$= Euler $\varphi$ fuction. But I am not sure if it has something to do with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the way to do it. Now find all $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = 2$.

**Hint 1.**

> If $p$ is a prime, and $p^2 \mid n$, then $p \mid \varphi(n)$.

**Hint 2.**

> If $p$ is a prime, and $p \mid n$, then $p-1 \mid \varphi(n)$.

Comment: This is your $666^\text{th}$ answer and your hat fits you nicely.

Comment: @GitGud, you mean the number of the... :-P

Comment: Ah, diabolic....+1